# Overwrite variable in console debugger mode in Pycharm 2019.2.4 without using Evaluate expression

Tags: pycharm

In previous versions of pycharm, it was possible to change variables on the fly regardless of the context straight in the console and without the use evaluate expression. In the version 2019.2.4 this capability was removed (see screenshots below, code stopped on blue line). Is there a way to configure pycharm to enable this capability?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known regression in PyCharm since 2019.2.3 version https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38378
Vote for it and feel free to leave comments.
You could temporarily downgrade to 2019.2.2